# Logging/Auditing 403 Requests

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, logging

I'm trying to establish the best way to log an attempted unauthorized access to a Controller/Action with .net mvc, basically the requirements are:

1. If they are not logged in then we want to redirect them to the login page
2. If they are logged in but don't have the right credentials for a page then we want to log information about the request, who they are, some HttpRequest stuff etc then redirect them to a specific unauthorised access page.

1 is obviously handled by default with .net mvc [Authorize] attribute filters. 2 I've partially implemented, I've created a specific Authorization attribute that extends the Authorize action filter that overrides the default HandleUnauthorizedRequest method to check a few extra things and return a HttpResult with the response code 403.

I'm having trouble implementing the other part of that, the logging the information to the database. There is of course the simple solution of logging it from within the custom attribute itself but that doesn't feel right, it feels like I'm making the attribute itself smarter then it should be, at the end of the day it should just know about restricting access and not about logging information to the database.

There is again the other solution of logging it when it gets to the Unauthorised page itself which doesn't feel as bad but still doesn't feel quite right.

Personally I'd like to be able to handle it somewhere within the request chain but as far as I can tell there's no place where I have access to all the right information. I've tried looking around here but haven't found anything that quite fits the solution we're going for.

Has anybody out there implemented something similar to what we're going for or have any ideas as to where this should be implemented.

Thanks,
MD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new IHttpModule and log the cheating hacker on the EndRequest event...

E.g.

```
public class UnAuthorizedLoggerHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += ContextOnEndRequest;
    }

    private void ContextOnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var app = sender as HttpApplication;

        if (app == null) return;

        if (app.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            //Log the error
            //All the user info should be in app.Request
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant, exactly what we were looking for!